# Running Android with data functionality from a laptop with a SIM card slot

Tags: mobile-data, sim-card, android-pc

I have always worked with laptops and amnt a fan of smartphones or tablets,
But I will soon be required to use an app, which doesn't have a desktop alternative, meaning I will need an Android-capable device.

So I was thinking could I run Android off of a desktop
and as I will also need my SIM card from my cell phone,
I was looking at the Lenovo ThinkPad X250
as it comes with a SIM card slot.

And I know Android can be loaded onto a laptop using the likes of
Bliss OS or Android x64

But I have read that people have had issues with connecting to the mobile data from the SIM card when using Android this way and was wondering if anybody knows any good ways to accomplish this.

Comment: BlueTooth has a profile that allows "SIM card roaming". It was developed to be able to use a SIM in a smartphone from your car cellular system (the antennas of the car are usually better and not shielded by the car itself). But I have not heard that such a profile can be used with a Laptop.

Comment: Not really the answer to the title, but perhaps mobile/portable WiFi may be more practical?